# sj:submit with targets and errorElementId not rendering properly

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a struts application, In one of the pages I am using `sj:submit` to submit the page with targets and `errorElementId` attributes.I have used the Struts2 validations on the page and the result type are written so that the success will redirect to a div and the failure will redirect the action to the same div, using `errorElementId` like the following

```
<div id="errorDiv" >
<sj:submit targets="successDiv" errorElementDiv="errorDiv" />
</div>
<div id="successDiv">
</div>
```

On testing this page I am getting the success response to the successDiv as given in the targets attribute, but in case of validation errors I am expecting the page to return to the same div where the sj belongs ie the errorDiv , but then also the the page with validation errors are rendered in the successDiv like the following

[image]

the result types for the action are the following

```
<result name="success">jsp/process/processlist.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">jsp/process/addprocess.jsp</result>
```

Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.javawebdevelop.com/582612/) worked for me .
It uses a an interceptor called jsonValidationWorkflowStack , which will return the validation errors , which are handled by javascript .

Answer (score 2):

The `input` result

```
<result name="input">jsp/process/addprocess.jsp</result>
```

points to the JSP from which the request was made. When the validation interceptor added errors to the action this result is returned. But this result type is `dispatcher`. In this case the JSP page is rendered and returned with the response. After that a callback handler, probably `success`, added response text to the `div`.

Comment: Try to remove the input result. Do you understand what is going wrong?

Comment: But it is the default type when using struts2 validations, so how can I change that,I didn't get exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: What makes a difference between this type and the result?

Comment: Then explain what did you mean by "it is the default type".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74400/discussion-between-dileepvikram-and-roman-c).

Comment: I  mean input is the default name of the result returned whenever a validation error returned

Comment: But you said "default type", it has a different meaning.

Comment: ohh , sorry for that ,

Comment: I'm not sure if it works properly but you can try it on your own.